# MySQL changes to Kafka Using Debezium - Capturing only DDL stmts

Tags: mysql, debezium

Configured MySQL-Debezium for CDC. It was capturing DDL changes like create/Drop table, but not capturing DML events.
Using MySQL 8.0.11 and Embedded debezium version 0.8.3.Final.

No additional configurations were done in MySQL server while creating table.

Configuration bean is created with below code

```
@Bean
public io.debezium.config.Configuration customerConnector() {
        return io.debezium.config.Configuration.create()
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.CONNECTOR_CLASS, "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector")
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.OFFSET_STORAGE, "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.OFFSET_STORAGE_FILE_FILENAME, "path-to-file")
            .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", 60000)
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.ENGINE_NAME, "customer-mysql-connector")
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.SERVER_NAME, databaseServer)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.HOSTNAME, databaseServer)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.PORT, databasePort)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.USER, databaseUser)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.PASSWORD, databasePassword)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.DATABASE_WHITELIST, databaseSchemaName)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.TABLE_WHITELIST, databaseTable)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.DATABASE_HISTORY,
                    MemoryDatabaseHistory.class.getName()).build();
}
```

Below is the log when starting it as Springboot application

```
2020-05-29 21:24:28.028  INFO 5576 --- [pool-1-thread-1] i.d.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask   : MySQL has the binlog file 'binlog.000009' required by the connector
2020-05-29 21:24:28.072  INFO 5576 --- [pool-1-thread-1] io.debezium.util.Threads                 : Requested thread factory for connector MySqlConnector, id = localhost named = binlog-client
2020-05-29 21:24:28.074  INFO 5576 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-29 21:24:28.074  INFO 5576 --- [pool-1-thread-1] io.debezium.util.Threads                 : Creating thread debezium-mysqlconnector-localhost-binlog-client
2020-05-29 21:24:28.090  INFO 5576 --- [-localhost:3306] io.debezium.util.Threads                 : Creating thread debezium-mysqlconnector-localhost-binlog-client
2020-05-29 21:24:28.121  INFO 5576 --- [-localhost:3306] c.g.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient  : Connected to localhost:3306 at binlog.000009/3786 (sid:6293, cid:36)
2020-05-29 21:24:28.121  INFO 5576 --- [-localhost:3306] i.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader  : Connected to MySQL binlog at localhost:3306, starting at binlog file 'binlog.000009', pos=3786, skipping 8 events plus 0 rows
2020-05-29 21:24:28.121  INFO 5576 --- [-localhost:3306] io.debezium.util.Threads                 : Creating thread debezium-mysqlconnector-localhost-binlog-client
2020-05-29 21:24:28.183  INFO 5576 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2020-05-29 21:24:28.199  INFO 5576 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2020-05-29 21:24:28.199  INFO 5576 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
```

Any Clue?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share your database and table filter settings?

Comment: Hi,

You mean the binlog setting? Pls find below

SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
SET GLOBAL binlog_row_image = 'full';
SET GLOBAL binlog_expire_logs_seconds  = 172800

**The DB version is 8.0.11**

Comment: No, I mean `databes.whitelist` and `table.whitelist`.

Comment: _SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
SET GLOBAL binlog_row_image = 'full';_

**CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON \*.\* TO 'user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**

_create database source;_

**create table customer (id varchar(10), name varchar(50), number varchar(10), email varchar(30), address varchar(200), primary key(id));**

Comment: I need to se the content of variables `databaseSchemaName` and `databaseTable` from lines
```
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.DATABASE_WHITELIST, databaseSchemaName)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.TABLE_WHITELIST, databaseTable)
```

Comment: **databaseSchemaName=source** _databaseTable=customer_; customer table created as **create table customer (id varchar(10), name varchar(50), number varchar(10), email varchar(30), address varchar(200), primary key(id));**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table.whitelist` should be set to to `<schema>.<table>` so in your case `source.customer`

Comment: HI Jiri, thanks for your time on this, i shall change that and update you.